# Exclude folders when redirect with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a question.
I want to redirect domain.com/var to domain.com/id=var
I can do that, but when users write a var like my folders, the htaccess redirect to the folder first :/

This is my actual htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-+/]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-+/]+)/$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

But when the user write for example css, the htacces redirecto to domain.com/css/?id=css
And the second problem is if the user put / after the var, example domain.com/var/

How can I change that? Thx 4 all!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to skip files/directories from rewriting:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9+/-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```